# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'cv2.cuda_GpuMat' and 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am using GPU accelerator in OpenCV, but I have problem with numpy threshold control as in CPU, how can I use threshold control for gpu script in object detection?

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'cv2.cuda_GpuMat' and 'float'
```

```py
gsrc.upload(source)
gtmpl.upload(need)

matcher = cv.cuda.createTemplateMatching(cv.CV_8UC1, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
gresult = matcher.match(gsrc, gtmpl)


gresult = matcher.match(gsrc, gtmpl)
resultg = gresult.download()
min_valg, max_valg, min_locg, max_locg = cv.minMaxLoc(resultg)

loc = np.where( gresult >= threshold)
```

Comment: so **download** the GpuMat's contents. then you can use numpy on the data.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, by giving an example. resultg = gresult.download() already download

Comment: yes you did, but you didn't *use the result* of that in the `>=` expression. you used the GpuMat instead, which caused the error. do you see a difference between `gresult` and `resultg`? I'd suggest less error-prone naming conventions.